# SQL to add rows in result when condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add new rows in the result when a combination of badge_codes are earned.

```
user    badge_code
------- ----------
Jim     2 
George  4
Jim     5
Mike    2
```

For example, if a user achieves badge_code #2 and #5, like Jim did, then include another row -- they've reached a new badge_code #10 based on that combination.

```
user    badge_code
------- ----------
Jim     2 
George  4
Jim     5
Mike    2
Jim     10
```

I suspect I'll need a union to add the row, but can't crack the nut on doing that based on a condition from each user's previous rows. I'm using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select user, badge_code
from t
union all
select user, 10
from t
where badge_code in (2, 5)
group by user
having count(*) = 2;
```

This formulation assumes that users only earn a badge code once.  If they can earn the same one multiple times, then use `count(distinct badge_code) = 2` instead.

Comment: That worked. The same badge_code CAN be earned more than once, so you should get extra credit for that add-on. Thanks!